# Communication Options : Android client- Java server

Tags: java, android, rest, sockets

I am in the process of developing my own java server and android client application..

I have study over the last weeks over the most appropriate communication that my app should have, an http connection (Restful server) or a tcp connection with sockets in which i am more familiar with?

***this is what my app and server will exchange through internet***

1. Authentication information (password, username)(encrypted)
2. Location information through gps
3. Upload/download images
4. I dont know if it really matters but notifications will be also needed as well as authentication through facebook and gmail account(if possible).

I am asking not because i want know which is faster but which of them is easier to implement, more reliable and more appropriate to my application's need

thanks!!

Comment: Use a HTTP connection. It will be easier to maintain, easier to use for you, both on the client and on the server side (Lots of libraries, most server side environments use HTTP), more reliable, encryption is built in (HTTPS)... I wouldn't use sockets for anything like this. (Also: your question is basically asking for an an opinion, and opinion-based questions aren't really suitable for Stack Overflow)

Comment: ( In my firm belief Stack overflow is a forum where opinions are listed for computing matters ).. thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use HTTPS with a properly configured server: TLS 1.2 and Perfect Forward Secrecy.

Pin the server certificate in the client.

It is best to sent the user credentials as a POST, Get parameters often end up in server logs.

Point 1: The HTTPS connection will encrypt the data in transit, there is no need for additional encryption.

Comment: So Rest-ful server is more reasonable..
And also you advice me to use https only,  even though some infos does not need encryption ?(or is a stupid question)

Comment: The move is to HTTPS everywhere, on current systems it does not impose much of an execution penalty. As an example an iPhone6 can AES encrypt about 400MB/s. Further, getting cryptographic security correct (secure) is hard.